# Why do vaccines sometimes induce a fever?

Tags: human-biology, immunology, medicine, immune-system, vaccination

How does a vaccine cause an immune response such as fever? Why do only some people experience these reactions? Why might those reactions change upon subsequent doses of the same or similar vaccines?

Comment: Does this related question help?: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/855/how-does-the-immune-system-learn-from-a-vaccine?rq=1

Comment: Yes, that's a useful link!  Wish there were something about side-effects like fevers, though.